# Unable to locate package, which has been installed

Tags: npm, homestead

I am using homestead environment with Vagrant version 2.2.4, homestead 7.2.1 and npm 6.7.0.

I am attempting to install and use a module called 'vuetify-material-dashboard'.

I've installed the module with npm

```
npm install --save vuetify-material-dashboard
```

I've loaded the module in my app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
import { TableComponent, TableColumn } from 'vue-table-component';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Card from 'vuetify-material-dashboard';

Vue.component('table-component', TableComponent);
Vue.component('table-column', TableColumn);

Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.use(Card);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter(routes),


});
```

However, upon running npm run dev / npm run watch-poll I get the error

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetify-material-dashboard' in 'D:\Homestead_Projects\project\resources\js'
 @ ./resources/js/app.js 23:0-46 29:8-12
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/index.sass
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! @ dev: `cross-env node node_modules/cross-env/dist/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Interestingly the other modules which are installed do not throw an error upon compiling.

I've removed, rebuilt the node_modules from within homestead / locally but it doesn't resolve the issue.